# If $\gcd(x;y)=1$, why is $\gcd[(ax+by);(cx+dy)]=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I found this in a book:

> $\gcd(x;y)=1$
>
> prove that $\gcd[(x+4y);(2x+7y)]=1$

How can I prove this?

My reasoning is $\gcd(x;y)=1$ so with Bezout's we find $ax+by=1$ but I don't know how to continue?

Thanks

Comment: The more general result In the title is true if $ad-bc=\pm 1.$

Comment: thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Let $d = \gcd(x+4y,2x+7y)$. You have
$$2(x+4y)-(2x+7y)=y$$

so $d\mid y$. But $d\mid (x+4y)$, so $d\mid x$. So $d\mid\gcd(x,y)$, so $d=1$.

Comment: that makes sense, thanks